# Visual Studio Razor Page False Syntax Errors

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor

Whenever I use the @ sign with a Razor page, such as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if( @(ProjectName.NameSpace.booleanVariable) ) {
    doStuff();
}
</script>
```

then I get syntax error notifications all over the place that turn out fine after the conversion to HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(True) {
    doStuff();
}
</script>
```

This is just a simple example but it occurs in other places as well. I will cite other examples if they become necessary. I couldn't find an answer among other stackoverflow questions, but with such a basic question I assume one is around. Links to said question are encouraged.

edit: Realized I should show that examples are JS inside Razor Page.

Question Is: How do I prevent these syntax error notifications so that I can identify and manage real syntax errors easily.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but don't you have to put the `@` in front of the `if`?

Comment: The answer is "yes". I think 2013 is better but still not ideal with Razor syntax when switching between C# and HTML mode. Not sure how this would be helpful...

Comment: @chuex - why? Indeed if you need server side code you do `@if...`, but if you want JavaScript `if (true)...` than you should not be adding `@` in front...

Comment: Within Javascript, you should be able to surround your Razor code with single quotes and it should suppress the warnings, at least in my experience.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - you are correct. I mistook the original posting as C#. In javascript you would not put the `@` in front.

Comment: Generally doing what you do (mixing js and csharp) is a bad idea. You're better off doing something like `<input type="hidden" id="booleanVariable" value="@ProjectName.NameSpace.booleanVariable" />` and then get its value via js. tl;dr; don't mix backend and frontent.

Comment: @DanielSanchez could you give an example?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that does seem like a better way to access backend.

Comment: @JohnKraemer
if ('@Model.Property' == 'expectedValue')
{
    // do stuff
}
Whether this is good practice or not is another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "True" is a valid javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if( Boolean(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ProjectName.NameSpace.booleanVariable))) ) {
    doStuff();
}
</script>
```

Boolean() is javascript code, to avoid the Razor Warning message.

Json.Encode to convert booleanVariable to "true" or "false",

you can replace it with (ProjectName.NameSpace.booleanVariable ? "true" : "false")

I think what you really want is

```
@if(ProjectName.NameSpace.booleanVariable) {
{<script type="text/javascript">
    doStuff();
</script>}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Steven! Could you explain why, as in your top code example, using strings to represent true and false is preferred? Also, what is the advantage of placing the if statement outside the script?

Comment: in c# boolean.ToString() will output True/False, True and False is not valid javascript, javascript is case sensitive, You should convert it to true/false, something like boolean.ToString().ToLower()

Comment: if I understand it correctly, your if condition is determined at server side(c#), and will never change in client side(javascript), if the condition is false, there is no point to output it to the client, that's why i place the if statement outisde the script as c# code

Comment: Seems like the all-around best answer. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Daniel Sanchez.

I successfully suppressed the notifications like so:

```
'@ProjectName.NameSpace.booleanVariable'
```

However, Steve said this isn't the best coding practice and the value should be stored with HTML and accessed via js.

```
<input type="hidden" id="booleanVariable" value="@ProjectName.NameSpace.booleanVariable" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: suggestion to put value in HTML is by Steve, not me. It likely better approach as it will let you separate HTML from JS. I would put value into data attribute instead like `<div data-some-value="@ProjectName.NameSpace.booleanVariable" ...>`.

Comment: One more note: `true.ToString()` returns `True` which will produce invalid JavaScript - be careful with casing.

Comment: I'm still very new to JS. is .ToString() called by default in this occasion?

Comment: `@` in Razor essentially is call to `ToString()`. So it is very surprising that you are getting `if (true)` in HTML as result of something like `if (@(true)) ...` in CSHTML.

Comment: Checked the page source HTML being output from razor. It was in fact output as True with capital T. Thanks for the explanation.